# Adding several columns into a data set

Tags: r

I  have a dataset and I want to add several columns into the dataset in just one step. I was wondering how I can do that (such as dplyr package). For example

```
R<-seq(1:5)
B<-c(15,16,17,18,19)
f<-c(20,21,22,23,24)
S<-data.frame(R,B,f)
```

Now I want to add several columns to the data set such as

```
g=B/f
h=round(B/f*f,3)
d=B+f/f
```

Comment: `S$g <- B/f` etc

Comment: just use '$' operator like S$g = B/f

Comment: @ Biranjan, thanks for the reply. But I prefer to use something more advance like dplyr package.

Comment: I see no reason to use dplyr however if you wish `S <- S %>% mutate(g = B/f)`

Comment: @ Biranjan, because I have a lot of functions and I want to add around 12 columns into the data set so I thought maybe If I could make them in just one step it would be good.

Comment: @ Biranjan, How can I use mutate for several functions?

Comment: just add ',' `S <- S %>% mutate(g = B/f,d=B+f/,h=round(B/f*f,3))`

Comment: or since you already seem to have calculated your columns: `S=dplyr::mutate(S,g,h,d)`

Comment: @ Biranjan, thanks so much for your help.